# Truncate and Insert

Tags: insert, truncate

I am connecting to oracle using an ETL tool.The operation what I am doing is truncating an existing table and inserting records into that table from a different table. This is working fine for 15 to 20 cycles of job run. After that my job got stuck in the portion where its inserting record.Is there anything wrong which I am doing here. Please find the query I am using below.Could some one help on this, from the previous experience.

```
    truncate table TABLE1;
        insert into TABLE1  select * from TABLE_SRC where TYPE in('MP','DA') 
and ID in(select ID from TABLE_SRC where TYPE in('MP','DA') and FLAG='Y');
        commit;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the table is going in lock situation.
Check with dba’s . 
Select * from dba_lock ;

Comment: But I am not sure how a truncate statement will lock the table.There is no other process which is loading this table